# I get unexpected T_VARIABLE error when i open facebook application with this code.Please make this code correct

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

```
  <?php
        session_start();
        require_once 'facebook.php';
        $app_id = "418907881455014";
        $app_secret = "36389d2c4caaf6de86982cb87686a494";
        $redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com'
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $app_id,
                'secret' => $app_secret,
                'cookie' => true
        ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        $coded = $_REQUEST['code'];

        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $name = "".$user_profile['name']."";
        $fbid = "".$user_profile['id']."";

        function RandomLine($filename) {
            $lines = file($filename) ;
            return $lines[array_rand($lines)] ;
        }
        $reason = RandomLine("reason.txt");  

        $canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg ("test3/bg.jpg");                                   // background image file
        $black = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 0, 0, 0 );                         // The second colour - to be used for the text
        $font = "arial.ttf";                                                         // Path to the font you are going to use
        $fontsize = 20;                                                             // font size

        $birthday = "".$user_profile['birthday']."";
        $death = "- ".date('d/m/Y', strtotime( '+'.rand(0, 10000).' days'))."";

        imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 120, $black, $font, $name );            // name
        imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 170, $black, $font, $birthday );        // birthday
        imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 255, 172, $black, $font, $death );           // death
        imagettftext( $canvas, 20, -1, 110, 220, $black, $font, $reason );           // reason

        imagejpeg( $canvas, "img/".$fbid.".jpg", 50 );

        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        //Create an album
        $album_details = array(
                'message'=> 'How will you die?',
                'name'=> 'How will you die?'
        );
        $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

        //Get album ID of the album you've just created
        $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

        //Upload a photo to album of ID...

        $file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file

        $photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find out here: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Fun-Land/353713864642723?sk=app_270399073027751'image' => '@' . realpath($file) );
        $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

        $upphoto = $upload_photo['id'];


        ImageDestroy( $canvas );

        header("Location: http://facebook.com".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto."")
        ?>
```

Well, i am not a programmer.So, i dont know what is the error in this code. I have uploaded this index.php script to web hosting , but when i open my facebook application the error comes is - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 7 . Please help me in making this code correct.

Answer (score 2):

Error indicates line 7, so it's probably nearby.

You're missing the ending semicolon on the previous (sixth) line.

```
$redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com'
```

That's why the variable on line 7 is unexpected.

---

On a different note, StackOverflow's syntax highlighting alerted me to another issue farther down. On this line:

```
$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find...51'image' => '@'.realpath($file));
```

Looks like you're not closing that first array element, and it probably should be like:

```
$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find...51', 'image' => '@'.realpath($file));
```

Comment: WEll , thank you very much till now , But please help me further , i am not a programmer. I got an another error- Fatal error: Call to undefined function facebook() in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 7 . What to do now ?

Comment: Are you there ?? Please help me in making this code correct.. Well i will really appreciate :'(

Comment: @NishantGhodke Hmm, hard to say. Line 7 tries to create a new instance of the "Facebook" class, but that fails for some reason. I would think the "Facebook" class would be defined in the "facebook.php" file (which is included on line 3). Do you still have line 3 in your code? Is the "Facebook" class defined in the facebook.php file? (Might look like `class Facebook` [like this](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php).)

Comment: Well i have this facebook.php on my web hosting - http://pastebin.com/GF69gW2F .. Check this facebook.php code

Comment: @NishantGhodke It looks okay to me. The "Facebook" class is defined starting on line 114 (`class Facebook`). I'm not sure why you're getting that error. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Line 7 is missing a semi-colon:

```
    $redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com'
```

should be this

```
    $redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com';
```