# Fatal error: Call to undefined function facebook() in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 7 . Please help in making this code correct

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "418907881455014";
$app_secret = "36389d2c4caaf6de86982cb87686a494";
$redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com';
$facebook = Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

$coded = $_REQUEST['code'];

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$name = "".$user_profile['name']."";
$fbid = "".$user_profile['id']."";

function RandomLine($filename) {
    $lines = file($filename) ;
    return $lines[array_rand($lines)] ;
}
$reason = RandomLine("reason.txt");  

$canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg ("test3/bg.jpg");                                   // background image file
$black = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 0, 0, 0 );                         // The second colour - to be used for the text
$font = "arial.ttf";                                                         // Path to the font you are going to use
$fontsize = 20;                                                             // font size

$birthday = "".$user_profile['birthday']."";
$death = "- ".date('d/m/Y', strtotime( '+'.rand(0, 10000).' days'))."";

imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 120, $black, $font, $name );            // name
imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 170, $black, $font, $birthday );        // birthday
imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 255, 172, $black, $font, $death );           // death
imagettftext( $canvas, 20, -1, 110, 220, $black, $font, $reason );           // reason

imagejpeg( $canvas, "img/".$fbid.".jpg", 50 );

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

//Create an album
$album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'How will you die?',
        'name'=> 'How will you die?'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Upload a photo to album of ID...

$file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file

$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find...51', 'image' => '@'.realpath($file));
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

$upphoto = $upload_photo['id'];


ImageDestroy( $canvas );

header("Location: http://facebook.com".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto."")
?>
```

This is this facebook.php file i am using- http://pastebin.com/GF69gW2F. But everytime i open my facebook application it gives me the fatat error Call to undefined function facebook() in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 7. I am not a programmer so that i could know what really is wrong in this code. I am trying to make facebook application with this code.Help me out.

Comment: If you're not a programmer, you're in the wrong place. You'll want to hire one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [`new` keyword](http://php.net/new) before trying to instantiate a `Facebook` object, though it appeared that you did have it in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352158/i-get-unexpected-t-variable-error-when-i-open-facebook-application-with-this-cod).

This line:

```
$facebook = Facebook(array(
```

should be

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
```

Comment: @NishantGhodke You're welcome! If my answer to your other question was sufficiently helpful, don't forget to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

line 7: like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
```